# Why parameter substitution in HQL-Query failed but native type succeeds?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, persistence, hql

did one of you ever had the problem that parameter substitution in a HQL-Query didn't worked?

I'm using hibernate for some, I think, simple queries getting entities from my MySQL Database.

Here are the Queries:

```
entityManager.
            createQuery("SELECT c FROM PersistentEvent c WHERE c.sessionId LIKE :sessionId").
            setParameter("sessionId", session.getId()).getResultList();
```

Doesn't get  a result! Under debugging I saw *session.getId()* returns the right value.

```
entityManager.
                createQuery("SELECT c FROM PersistentEvent c WHERE c.sessionId LIKE :sessionId").
                setParameter("sessionId", "TestSessionId - 1").getResultList();
```

Works for my testdata where such an entry exists.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Turn on "show_sql" in your Hibernate/JPA settings and post the query.

Comment: `select persistent0_.id as id0_, persistent0_.date as date0_, persistent0_.description as descript3_0_, persistent0_.sessionId as sessionId0_ from event persistent0_ where persistent0_.sessionId like ?` and for debug output of log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL I get `[TRACE] -  returning 'TestSession - 1' as column: id3_` and `[TRACE] -  binding 'TestSession - 1' to parameter: 1`

Comment: Your hardcoded example passes in `TestSessionId - 1` and not `TestSession - 1` which is in the query. Could that be the problem?

Comment: You rescued my night man. But first I'll get a brake. Doh!

Comment: No problem! I converted my comment to an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you posted the query Hibernate was generating, I noticed that `session.getId()` was inserting  `TestSession - 1` instead of `TestSessionId - 1`, which was in your hard coded example.